# Quiz scoring script not working right

Tags: php, arrays

I'm testing a quiz with ten questions. All are multiple choice except for the second one (fill-in-the-blank) and the last one, which requires a user to select three out of six checkboxes.

This is the answer key and scoring script:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 $correct = 0;
 $answers = array(1 => array('A'), 
             2 => array('Mars'), 
             3 => array('C'), 
             4 => array('D'), 
             5 => array('A'), 
             6 => array('C'), 
             7 => 'C', 
             8 => 'C', 
             9 => 'B', 
             10 => array('A','B','C'));
$total = count($answers);

foreach($answers as $num => $answer){
    $qa = $_POST['q'.$num.''];

if(is_array($answer)){
    if(array_diff($qa, $answer) == array()){
        $correct++;
    }
} else if($qa === $answer){
    $correct++;
 }

 $grade= ($correct/count($answers))*100;
 }
}
echo '<div style="background: #ff0;">Score '.$grade.'%</div>';
echo '<br>var_dump: ';
var_dump($_POST);
```

If I get all ten questions correct, it displays the correct array (below), but I only get a score of 70% instead of 100%. If I get the first two questions wrong but all the others correct, I get 50%, instead of 80%.

Can anyone see a problem with my scoring script, or do you think the problem lies elsewhere in my quiz code?

```
var_dump: array(12) { ["q1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } ["q2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Mars" } ["q3"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "C" } ["q4"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "D" } ["q5"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } ["q6"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "C" } ["q7"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "C" } ["q8"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "C" } ["q9"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } ["q10"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "B" [2]=> string(1) "C" } ["PreviousURL"]=> string(25) "http://g1/test/gw-intro" ["user_token"]=> string(13) "54f3d1ac48555" }
```

Comment: In `$answers`, elements 7, 8 and 9 are single elements, while in your `$_POST` the corresponding items are arrays. That would explain the 30% difference in scoring.

Comment: Yikes, I don't know how I did that. I fixed it, but the scoring is still all over the map; if I get the first four questions correct, I now get a score of 100%. Maybe I'll have to display only certain types of questions (e.g. multiple choice) and see if I can isolate the problem.

Comment: It looks like the score is based on the number of questions answered. So if you only answer one question, and you get it right, you're getting 1 out of 1 right = 100%. Each question that isn't answered should subtract 10% from the score.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that was a lame question. I verified that the scoring script IS working. The only problem is that, if you don't answer a particular question, it isn't counted as wrong. So if you just answer ONE question and you get it right, that's 1 out of 1, or 100%, when it should be 10%.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this answers your question - it worked in the random trials I did. Let me know if it's not working as you'd like, and please provide more details about why it isn't.

```
<?php
$correct = $answered = 0; //Correct Total.
$answers = array(1 => array('A'), 
         2 => array('Mars'), 
         3 => array('C'), 
         4 => array('D'), 
         5 => array('A'), 
         6 => array('C'), 
         7 => 'C', 
         8 => 'C', 
         9 => 'B', 
         10 => array('A','B','C'));
$_POST = [
    'q1'=>['A'],
    'q2'=>['Mars'],
    'q3'=>['C'],
    'q4'=>['D'],
    'q5'=>['A'],
    'q6'=>['C'],
    'q7'=>'C',
    'q8'=>'C'

]; //I did this to run the algorithm without needing to make up a form.
foreach($answers as $key => $values){
    if(!key_exists('q'.$key, $_POST)) //Key does not exist in the POST data sent by the browser, answer is therefore wrong.
        $answered++; //Increase the "answered" count, but do not increase the correct count 
    else{
        $answer = $_POST['q'.$key];
        if($answer === $values){ 
            //If the answer is exactly equal to the value in the answer array, it is correct.
            //I'm assuming you format the answers as you need.

            $correct++;
            $answered++;
        }else{
            $answered++;
        }
    }

}
echo "Your Score is: {$correct}/{$answered}, or ". (($correct/$answered)*100)."%";
```

?>